# How can I replace a broken ribbon circuit board in a Dualshock 3?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, controllers

I have a Dualshock 3 and apparently, its ribbon circuit board (code `SA1Q147A`) is broken.

I cannot find this particular model anywhere, either in my country, on the web, or on overseas sale sites. There are 2-3 sites that say they sell this model but they didn't fill me with confidence - they seemed kinda like scam sites.

What I have been able to find, are two different models: `SA1Q135A` and `SA1Q160A`. My question is, if a buy one of these, will it work in my DS3 controller? Or is there another solution I could use?

Answer (score 2):

If there's no parts available, buy a scrapped PS3 controller off of eBay. Lots of people sell pre-broken controllers, and you may manage to find one with the ribbon cable intact.


Although, while that is an option, you could purchase another PS3 controller and if your current one has a custom shell, move shells over.